# CSS Position:Overflow issue

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am trying to get the picture in the 2nd div to overflow the parent div. I have played around with different `position` attributes and `overflow:visible`, but none seem to solve my issue.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

EDIT: Okay scrap that first code - here is the actual code:
I want to get the slider to stretch across and overflow the sp_block
EDIT 2: I must not edit the first 4 divs by the way.

```
<div id="sp_header">

<div id="sp_block_16" class="sp_block_section_last">
    <div>
        <div class="sp_block">
            <!--

             must have 

            -->
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.dedicatedrejects.com/icsa/test/slider/allinone_contentSlider.css"></link>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin"></link>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dedicatedrejects.com/icsa/test/slider/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dedicatedrejects.com/icsa/test/slider/js/allinone_contentSlider.js"></script>
            <!--

             must have 

            -->
            <script></script>
            <div style="position:relative; width:1562px; height:351px; overflow:visible;">
                <div style="width:1562px; height:351px; position:absolute; overflow:visible; margin: 0 auto;">
                    <div class="allinone_contentSlider imposing" style="width: 1562px; height: 351px;">
                        <div id="allinone_contentSlider_imposing" style="position:relative overflow:visible;"></div>
                        <div class="bottomNavRight" style="display: block; bottom: -35px; top: auto; left: 813px;"></div>
                        <div class="bottomNav" style="display: block; bottom: -35px; top: auto; width: 46px; left: 758px;"></div>
                        <div class="bottomNavLeft" style="display: block; bottom: -35px; top: auto; left: 758px;"></div>
                        <div class="bannerControls" style="margin-top: 105px;"></div>
                        <div class="contentHolderVisibleWrapper" style="width: 1562px; height: 351px;">
                            <div class="contentHolder ui-draggable" style="cursor: url("skins/hand.cur"), url("skins/hand.cur"), move; … top: 0px; position: absolute; width: 3124px; height: 351px;">
                                <div id="contentHolderUnit_0" class="contentHolderUnit" rel="0" style="width: 1562px; height: 351px;">
                                    <img src="https://robertsspaceindustries.com/media/6kahqz455yu40r/post_section_header/StarCitizenDev-2014-04-11-14-10-32-75.jpg" style="position:absolute;"></img>
                                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vcifs31.png" style="position:absolute; z-index:10;"></img>
                                </div>
                                <div id="allinone_contentSlider_photoText0" class="allinone_contentSlider_texts" style="z-index: 11; width: 1562px; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: none;"></div>
                                <div id="contentHolderUnit_1" class="contentHolderUnit" rel="1" style="width: 1562px; height: 351px;"></div>
                                <div id="allinone_contentSlider_photoText1" class="allinone_contentSlider_texts" style="z-index: 11; width: 1562px; left: 1562px; top: 0px; display: none;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="playOver" style="left: 744px; top: 139px; display: none;"></div>
                        <canvas class="mycanvas" width="36" height="36"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and whee's the CSS that you're using..?

Comment: There is no inline CSS in your code, just a couple of (invalid) HTML attributes. Please show your actual code.

Comment: better avoid using inline styles. [Why Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Comment: I'm guessing you have to use inline styles for lack of access or something—right?

I'd guess that something to do with the slider is preventing the overflow of the child elements within it. Inspect all the elements on your staging site that wrap the slider content. Are any of them hiding overflow? If so, try disabling it.

Comment: Correct. The code that I am inserting is a so called "custom page" on a forum platform which entire code can't really be edited...

Answer (score 0):

As it is, the image will appear outside the parent div, for no overflow has been specified. If you want it to hide inside the parent div, just add to the div:

```
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cn3n3/2/

Comment: No, I need it to overflow. I tried adding overflow:visible to the middle div, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Then add no overflow. See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Cn3n3/2/ on the first case.

Answer (score 0):

The inline width and height attributes (within the `<img>` tag) shouldn't have the `px` unit in them. Only specify the number of pixels without a unit. You shouldn't need to specify overflow, since the defaults will suit your needs in this case.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/orvn/ansBc/1/

```
<div id="container">
   <img src="http://foo.com/image.jpg" width="500">
</div>

#container { width: 300px; }
#container > img { display: block; }
```

Additionally, you don't need to wrap the image in a div here, you can apply `display: block;` to have it behave the way a div would.

Comment: I think my problem was more complicated than I thought - I attached the actual code as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve but the parent div needs the overflow tag.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">image</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
width:700px;
height:200px;
overflow:visible;
background-color:green;
}

.child {
    width:1000px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Here is a demo [jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/Gg6PY/)

I made the parent div background height longer so you can see the overflow. You can also replace the background color with an image. Replace the class (parent & Child) and write this inline but I advise against that.